# TouchMoved is SwipeGesture

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitouch

I am using swipe gesture recognizer.but when i do touchMoved slowly, swipeGesture event is called…is there anyway to avoid it?i want to do different operation in SwipeGesture and TouchMoved.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a property of [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) called cancelsTouchesInView.  If you set that to NO, you will be able to receive touchesMoved events even while tracking a swipe gesture.  Is this what you're after?